# make the form pause after a submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to design a Login form let's say something like this:

```
<form action="target.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="user" id="user" /><br /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
</from>
```

what I'm trying to do is to make the form show some pic.gif for 3 seconds when user hits submit and then continue  I don't want it to start the next process directly.

Comment: I'm aware that this is not ux.stackexchange.com, but why would you want the user to wait, artificially?

Comment: can i show the pic.gif without him waiting?

Comment: yes if you have the pic.gif already in browser cache. and no guarantee if the image loads in 3 secs, right? better option css caheing/preloadin the image

Comment: You can use javascript (click function & counter) to show the user your gif then use `document.forms["Your Form NAME"].submit();` to submit your form after the counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you can just use the setTimeout() function.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" onclick="window.setTimeout(doStuffAfter, 30000)">
```

You call it in whatever way you want with func being the called after the delay. So you can open the image and then navigate away once the delay is done.

```
 window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Comment: This solution is missing a few parts. You need to display `pic.gif` *before* setting the timeout for submission. You also need to prevent the default behavior of the `input` by adding `; return false;` to the end of the `onclick` handler. And then you'll have to manually submit the form in the setTimeout handler, with `theForm.submit()`.

Comment: thanks man i got the idea

Answer (score 3):

Have your image initially with style "display:none" and modify your form declaration to hanlde "onsubmit" event:

```
<form action="target.php" method="POST" onsubmit = "mySubmit(this)">
```

and then define function:

```
function mySubmit(frm) {
    document.getElementById("myImg").style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(function() {frm.submit()}, 3000);
    return false;
}
```

It will display your image and cancel original submit request. But after 3 seconds it will submit form from code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('form').submit(function () {
  if (showPic()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

From a UX perspective I recommend giving them a prompt in your pic.